# How to get product's list by particular vendor through REST API Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I am using WP REST API and woo commerce API for multi store application, How can i  get product's list by particular vendor through REST API WordPress.

Comment: which plugin are you used for multivendor?

Comment: i am using WC vendor (http://wcvendors.com/)